# don't understand why const qualifiers are discarded

Tags: c++, constants

I know this is a simple question, but I have googled for some time, and from what I found I still don't understand the problem.
I have this simple code:

```
class X {
    public:
        X() : x_(42) {};
        virtual const long long f() const {
            return do_f();
        }
    protected:
        virtual const long long do_f() const {
            return x_;
        }
        long long x_;
};

auto main() -> int {
    X x;
    x.f();
}
```

I expect it to compile, because I don't see how these methods modify object of X.
But obviously I miss something, because:

```
rakul@lucky-star /tmp $ g++ --std=c++14 -Werror=ignored-qualifiers 1.cpp        
1.cpp:6:37: error: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Werror=ignored-qualifiers]
         virtual const long long f() const {
                                     ^
1.cpp:10:40: error: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Werror=ignored-qualifiers]
         virtual const long long do_f() const {
                                        ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
rakul@lucky-star /tmp $
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The const errors you are getting are not related to the `const`qualifier of the function (the last `const`), but to the `const` qualifier of the return type (the first `const`).

Since they are integer types and they are returned by value, not by reference, so they do not need the `const`qualifier. This applies for all types (built in or user defined) which are **returned by value**.

So the definition of your functions should be as follows:

```
    virtual long long f() const;
    virtual long long do_f() const;
```

Comment: "Since they are integer types, they are returned by value, not by reference, so they do not need the constqualifier." I disagree - the return type makes no difference. You can return an integer by reference, and then the `const` would make complete sense.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore ok, sentence rewritten.